# Trying to create a build process on AIX 6.1

Tags: c++, gnu-make, aix, xlc

I'm trying to update a client's build process. My client is using IBM P6's running AIX 6.1. My client has been able to compile and build C++ and C code on similar systems, but not the particular one I'm working on.

I've made sure that the IBM directory containing xlc is in my $PATH. When I run gmake, I get an error stating that gmake can't find .orig/xlc_r.  I added the path for .orig to my $PATH and I still get the error.

I don't have the error listing in front of me, but it looks something like this:

gmake: xlc_r[11]: Can't find .orig/xlc_r

Is there another environment variable I need to set?

Thanks
pemeyer

Comment: This problem cannot be solved without providing actual information.

Comment: I will try to copy the actual message text and post it later today

Answer (score 1):

Which version of the compiler are you using, and was it installed using the instructions in the [installation guide](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGH3R_13.1.3/kc_gen/com.ibm.xlcpp1313.aix.doc_toc-gen8.html)?

In xlc_r, line 6 should be something like:

```
export XL_NDI_INSTALL=[path to base directory of the compiler]
```

and line 11 is:

```
exec ${XLCPP_NDI_INSTALL}/bin/.orig/$EXEC "$@"
```

So if `${XLCPP_NDI_INSTALL}` is set correctly, xlc_r should be able to find .orig/xlc_r.

The other thing to try is to `ls -l ${XLCPP_NDI_INSTALL}/bin/.orig/xlc_r` to make sure it points to an existing file.  If it points to a symlink, `ls -l` the symlink.  At the end it should point to a real `xlc` executable with execute permission.

Comment: Thanks, Rafik.  I'll take a look when I get to the office and make sure xlc_r looks like you describe.